# Inserting multiple records into a webSQL table using single query, data from array of objects

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, sqlite

Currently I'm looping an INSERT INTO query after pulling JSON from a server to put it into a webSQL database.

Whilst this works, I'm executing a SQL transaction for each record, this seems very inefficient especially on a mobile device.

Given that I have an array of objects that correspond to the values required for each row how can I do this without a loop? Or would it be better to simply loop through?

Roughly speaking I have an array in the following format:

```
[{"Timestamp": 323343553,
  "ID": 1,
  "Value1": "string"
  "Value2": 322}, ... more objects
]
```

Comment: You do the loop inside the transaction.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, do you have an example of a loop inside a transaction?

Answer (score 0):

As Cl told you can loop the insert SQL command into one transaction as follows.

```
var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'my first database', 2 * 1024 * 1024);

db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE user (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name)');
});

var userArray = [{"name": "bob"}, {  "name": "lee"}];

db.transaction(function (tx) {
    for (var i = 0; i <userArray.length; i++)
    {
        tx.executeSql("insert into user(name) values(?)",  [userArray[i].name],successCallBack,errorCallBack);

    }
});


function successCallBack(){
  console.log("inserted corrrectly !!");
}
function errorCallBack(tx,error){
   if (query.indexOf('insert into') === -1)
                alert("Error : " + error.message + " in " + query);
  console.log(error.message + "in" + tx);
}
```